# Why can't I use parens when executing function in return object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone explain why, if I add parens to `_start` in the return statement I get the error:

`undefined is not a function`

`_start` is function, is it not?

```
.factory('TrackPage', ['$location', function($location){

    var self = this;

    function _start(){
        //method body
    }

    function _end(){
       //method body
    }

    return {
        Start: _start,
        End: _end
    }
 }]);
```

The code works as is but I'd like to know why when `Start: ...` is `Start:  _start()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: There is probably something else going wrong here.  `_start` is declared as a function, it should be able to be invoked in the return.  Just running your example code with `Start: _start()` does not throw any errors.  I suspect that you have other code calling `Start.start()` and unless `_start` returns a function itself, that is going to throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add parens to `_start,`, you're assigning the **return value** of `_start` to `Start`.
This return value is `undefined`.

Then, when you try to execute `Start()`, you will get the `undefined is not a function` error.

This is because the return value of `_start` (`undefined`) is not a function.

So, the error is saying *"`Start` is not a function"*, instead of *"`_start` is not a function."*

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with angularjs, but usually when you store a function a() in a variable v you call the function by putting v(), where v = a. So if you put v = a() and call v() you end up with a()() instead. a() returns undefines and undefined() is not a function.

p.s. lacking reputation to make this a comment, so it's and answer instead.